# Convert XML to Dictionary<String,String>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have been trying to convert this XML to a dictionnary but have all kinds of errors. Here's my XML

```
<product>
        <name>AH</name>
        <prod>AH</prod>
        <time>Noon</time>
        <txt>00A</txt>
</product>
```

I'm trying to get a dictionary with the Key equal to the txt and the value to prod.
I have been trying this one but couldn't make it work:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = 
        (from e in productsNames.Descendants() select new KeyValuePair<string, string>
        (e.Element("txt").Value, e.Element("prod").Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x =>x.Value);
```

Can you help me? thanks in advance!

Comment: `image`, `facade`? Did you post the correct xml?

Comment: oops sorry just edited the code!

Comment: How does this fail? Exception? Compiler error? Unexpected result?

Comment: Got this: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ^^ basically: Find out, what exactly is null, then accommodate for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy :

```
            string xml = @"<product>
                                    <name>AH</name>
                                    <prod>AH</prod>
                                    <time>Noon</time>
                                    <txt>00A</txt>
                            </product>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("product")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("name"), y => (string)y.Element("prod"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```